# Can't make vim-plug work

Tags: vimrc, plugin-vim-plug

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04. I've decided to start using Vim, so I needed a plugin manager. I found vim-plug and I really liked it. But I can't make it work. I followed the installation guide:

```
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

Created .vimrc and pasted:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
call plug#end()
```

But Vim gives me Errors:

```
Error detected while processing /home/keltar/.vimrc:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: plug#begin
line    2:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
line    3:
E117: Unknown function: plug#end
```

What's wrong? Vim version is 8.0.95 .

`:scriptames` output:

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim80/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
  7: ~/.vimrc
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

`ls -la ~/.vim/autoload` output:

```
total 80
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 Apr 19 22:22 .
drwxr-x--- 3 root root  4096 Apr 19 22:22 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 71885 Apr 20 09:32 plug.vim
```

Comment: Did you checked that the curl command worked and that the file `~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim` exists and contains the code of vim-plug? (Also I don't think this is relevant to your problem, but I don't know how the `begin()` command works without argument, you might want to use `call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')` as specified in the doc)

Comment: @statox, Yes, that was a mistake, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: What's the output of `:scriptnames`?

Comment: @muru, I've added it to post.

Comment: Can you add output of `ls -la ~/.vim/autoload/`? Also have you copy-pasted those lines to your `.vimrc` or typed them by hand? If you copy-pasted, maybe there's some strange sign in there, so would be good to remove those lines and type them by hand.

Comment: @grodzik, here is a problem. Everything works with sudo. So I need to give special permission to this folder, needn't I?

Comment: why did you do it as root? You should not run those commands as root but as your default user.

Comment: Yup, in general, avoid using `sudo` when possible ;) But to fix that you I would advise to run `sudo chmod -R keltar:keltar ~/.vim` (assuming your user is `keltar` and users group is `keltar` - check with `ls -d ~`)

Comment: @grodzik, thank you so much. I'm new to Linux, so still learning all this things.

Comment: autoload/plug.vim is missing in :scriptnames.